# Workday: Usage Type is Invalid for this Contactable

Tags: data-integration, workday-api, snaplogic

We are using SnapLogic to load records into Workday. For `Put_Customer` of `Revenue_Management` web service, I was getting the following error:

[image: Put_Customer Usage Data required]

I was able to work around this problem by using the following fields:

- **Communication_Usage_Type_ID** for

  ```
  $Customer_Data.Business_Entity_Data.Contact_Data.Address_Data[*].Usage_Data[*].Type_Data[*].Type_Reference.ID[*].type
  ```
- **BUSINESS** for

  ```
  $Customer_Data.Business_Entity_Data.Contact_Data.Address_Data[*].Usage_Data[*].Type_Data[*].Type_Reference.ID[*].value
  ```

And I was able to post Customer records using `Put_Customer` of `Revenue_Management` web service. So, when I got the above error while using `Put_Business_Entity_Contact` of `Revenue_Management` web service for posting business contacts against the Customers I posted earlier, I thought that the same solution will work. **But it didn't**. Instead, it gave me the following error:

[image: Usage Type invalid]

As a result, I'm unable to post addresses, phone numbers, email addresses etc. Is there a work around for this?

Comment: Bilesh, you are saying that you want to use Get_Business_Entity_Contacts to "post business contacts". The method is meant to read contacts, so this confuses me. Can you clarify please?

Comment: @cdonner Its a mistake on my part. I meant `Put_Business_Entity_Contact`.

Comment: I believe "Home" and "Work" are valid usage types in a default instance. "BUSINESS" is not.

Comment: @cdonner Sorry for the late reply. Your suggestion worked. Now using 'WORK' instead of 'BUSINESS'.